# Fetch Data from REST API sends two requests and can't authenticate

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch data in my React app from an Django server with Django Rest Framework, I'm using the built in token authentication.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let headers = {
       "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Token <token is here>"
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/stats/', {
        headers: headers,
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ games: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
}
```

Inspecting the page in Chrome reveals this
[image: Chrome inspection]

This looks like two separate requests but I'm not sure.
The requests that has status `(failed)` has the headers I provided in React with in it. This request seems to have failed completely, it did not even reach the server.

The other request that has the status `401` doesn't have the headers I provided. The request did however get a response from the server.

Anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are you handling CORS correctly? What are the methods of those two requests? When requesting something from a different domain, browser first sends OPTIONS request to check CORS headers.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if you are sending the header correctly. I was unable to find `token` auth scheme anywhere (looked here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization). Can you try replacing it with `Bearer`?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see, The request that reaches the server but get's 401 response does have OPTIONS method. The other request that doesn't have a method specified. https://gyazo.com/c95411ae2cade5385c7aca2519e2b9ba

Comment: Ah, so that is the problem. This is nice library for managing CORS: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to do some reading, not very familiar with CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by [David Nováks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2465895/david-nov%C3%A1k) comment:

- Installed [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) in my django project.
- Added my React servers hosting address to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST.